# Editing sudo permissions with strange instructions

Tags: command-line, chromium

Hello I am using Ubuntu and trying to install Chromium OS. They recommend using Ubuntu, but when working through their [Quick Start guide](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/quick-start-guide) I ran [these commands from the "Prerequisites" step 3](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/tips-and-tricks-for-chromium-os-developers#TOC-Making-sudo-a-little-more-permissive):

```
cd /tmp
cat > ./sudo_editor <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
echo Defaults \!tty_tickets > \$1          # Entering your password in one shell affects all shells
echo Defaults timestamp_timeout=180 >> \$1 # Time between re-requesting your password, in minutes
EOF
chmod +x ./sudo_editor
sudo EDITOR=./sudo_editor visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/relax_requirements
```

and when entering this command:

```
sudo EDITOR=./sudo_editor visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/relax_requirements
```

the error was

```
fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'myname@example.(none)')
```

What should I do?

Comment: That looks like `git` error, but I don't see a git command being used.

Comment: My apologies if you feel I should take your question at face value, but I just want to make sure I understand your request.  I see that you are trying to install what I must assume is a SPECIAL DEVELOPERS VERSION of the Chromium OS.  What I feel I need to know to perhaps serve you better is to know if that is merely a coincidence and this is the only copy you've found, or if there is a particular reason you need this particular version.  If all you want is a functioning browser, I could offer you a wealth of advice.

Comment: I don't want a functional browser basically Chromium OS would be the best for my netbook from what I know....

Comment: um this is kinda related to linux because im downloading it via terminal using a linux os

Comment: @Eve I can't answer anymore, but like my comment in another Q- That link has crazy over-compicated instructions about just editing a sudoers file, I *think* it just adds a new file with 2 lines in it, this should do it too: `echo -e "Defaults !tty_tickets\nDefaults timestamp_timeout=180" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers.d/relax_requirements`  But I have no idea about the email address message...

Comment: And the original instructions being followed from http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/quick-start-guide say to Start with Ubuntu... chromium.org probably should make their own generic live iso that's easy to use, but for now they lead people to Ubuntu

Comment: Ok thank you @Xen2050 I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think it is etckeeper trying to commit the current state of the `/etc/` directory before `visudo`. That commit uses `git`, which tries to find or derive an email address to put into the author field of the commit - (which can not be changed later). Git finally gives up when it can not find settings, or even derive an email address.